# Django Dynamic Nested Formset

Tags: javascript, django, dynamic, nested, formset

I've been trying to figure out lately how create a nested formset where a user can dynamically add more forms to both the outer and inner form.

My use: I'm trying to allow users to enter workouts wherein they will have the option to add both more sets to an exercise as well as more exercises to the workout.  The number of sets per exercise and exercises per set

I've been able to add formsets dynamically with javascript, but I'm not sure how to handle to naming of the forms to do it with a nested formset?

Answer (score 0):

I use the stronglifts 5x5 android app so I am imagining you are making something like that. I wouldn't make that interface with Django forms because it has so many buttons, it would be annoying to wait for all the page refreshes. I would definitely look at it from a javascript asynch perspective. I'd have one view in django for the page, one for the asynch request handling, and most of the functionality in javascript.

PS, if you would like an answer to exactly your question, include some source code so guys can have something to work with.

Comment: I don't think quite like that because the number of sets and reps are both going to be entered in.  I need the user to be able to click a button to add a field to enter reps for a new set for a particular exercise and also to be able to click a button to add another exercise.  I haven't really come up with a way to attempt to tackle this so I have yet to put together much useful code.